# Update object value in a loop getting the same value on all items using Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js, object

I'm running in a loop which should update some values inside an object on vue environment.

I tried map, foreach & for loops but the specific property (e.g Id, or show) getting always the same values.

I took the same logic to **[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4scx6L2t/1/)** (i put part of the same data there for playing) and it's worked there.

Here is the code:

```
var data = t.data.map((item) => {
        item.Status = Status.Draft;
          if (item.IsSent) {
            item.Status = Status.Sent;
          }
          return item;
        });

data.forEach((item) => {
     item.Buttons.forEach((b, index) => {
          const id = { Id: "button_" + item.ID + "_" + index };
          let show = { show: false };
          switch (b.action) {
              case ButtonActions.Duplicate:
              case ButtonActions.Delete:
              case ButtonActions.Preview: {
                show = { show: true };
                break;
              }
              case ButtonActions.Reports:
              case ButtonActions.Groups: {
                if (item.IsSent) {
                  show = { show: true };
                } else {
                  show = { show: false };
                }
                break;
              }
              case ButtonActions.Send:
              case ButtonActions.Schedule:
              case ButtonActions.Edit: {
                if (item.IsSent) {
                  show = { show: false };
                } else {
                  show = { show: true };
                }
                break;
              }
            }
            Object.assign(b, id);
            Object.assign(b, show);
     });
    //console.log(item.Buttons);
});
```

button.id getting always **the same** id for all the buttons.
button.show can be true or false but **always the same** at all buttons no matter what loop i'm using,
the console show the expected value,
then after the loop, it is strange, the property is added but with the same values all over.

It looks like I found a Vue bug! :(

**Can someone help with it?**

Comment: Please post your data property so that more information could be obtained. Where is  the `ButtonActions` object coming from? Is that a Typescript interface?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, you can see the it in the jsfiddle, as numbers.

Comment: I was actually referring to the `data` property in Vue. That is `data() { return: {data }}`

Answer (score 1):

In the vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) regarding Reactivity caveats for objects,

It states:

*Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend(). However, new properties added to the object will not trigger changes. In such cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original object and the mixin object:*

```js
// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

So, in that vein, this should help

```js
b = Object.assign({}, b, { id, show })
```

Alternatively, you can use

```js
this.$set(b, 'show', show);
this.$set(b, 'id', id);
```

Comment: Yep, i tried both of these solutions, doesn't working. I opened an issue in GitHub. I tried all the existing options i know, loops, object assign, set, everything. Im here after all that.

Comment: That's very strange. I will look into it some more. In the meantime, do you think you could create a jsfiddle of the Vue version? the one that's currently on is in vanilla JS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, 
First, Thanks for the help,
Secondly, The code above here is in Vue, the jsFiddle is in js vanila using Vue library.
what exactly you mean when you say create jsfiddle of the vue version?
By the way, I agree, that's very strange. I opened an issue like i said.

Comment: I don;t think that code is in Vue.js. This is an example of a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dw83v7g/3/) written in Vue.js. Notice how under `FRAMEWORKS AND EXTENSION`, `No-library (PURE JS) `is selected?  Compare that to the example  I linked. Also, you need to initialise a vue instance . `new Vue({.....}}`.

Comment: I went to check a few other vue jsfiddle examples, and while they didn't always specify the `FRAMEWORKS AND EXTENSION`, bit, they always had a new Vue instance. My bad. [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/aump8a25/), [Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue) and [Example 3](https://jsfiddle.net/gambo/ep5a7tve/) do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks buddy, in addition to your solution, I changed the forEach scope to map, then return the new buttons object and re-initial it with the new button

Comment: That's great to hear, @Idoshhh. I am happy to have helped :). Please could you post your solution for the benefit of everyone who comes across this page.

Comment: Yep, i got out for now but later ill do that